# Return matched element in a List using lambdas

Tags: java, lambda

This works well and all:

```
// ActorDao
public Optional<Actor> read(long id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(actors.get((int) id));
}

public List<Actor> readAll() {
    // Return a list of actors from db  
}



// Demo
public static Actor getActor(String firstName, String lastName) {
    Dao<Actor> actorDao = new ActorDao();
    long id = 0;
    for (Actor actor : actorDao.readAll()) {
        if (firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(actor.getFirstName()) && lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(actor.getLastName())) {
            id = actor.getId() - 1; // actor_id in db starts at 1
            return actorDao.read(id).get();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

What would be the more elegant way in Java8+?

Comment: Some might give your question downvotes because it seems to be a code review question (optimization).

Comment: It is a legitimate question on how to work with lambas (objectively answerable) resulting to elegance. :)

Comment: What exactly is `Dao<Actor>`?

Comment: A generic interface. See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-pattern).

Comment: Aside: `actorDao.read(id).get()` looks like a code smell, an `Opional#get` without a presence check.

Comment: Is `Optional.ofNullable()` already a check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return actorDao.readAll()
        .stream()
        .filter(actor -> firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(actor.getFirstName()))
        .filter(actor -> lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(actor.getLastName()))
        .map(actor -> actorDao.read(actor.getId() - 1).get())
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you add a bit of explanation text to this please?

Comment: Anything specific?

Comment: Around `stream()`, `filter`, and `map`. :)

Comment: It's a bit much to explain in an answer. Take a look at the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html#pipelines).